# Map Box error in android studio

Tags: android

I'm actually doing an android app using MapBox, but I have this error :
Error:(10, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project .

> Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.2.0-beta.4@aar, build_3icgxfjmqrqje950n07dtodfa$_run_closure1$_closure3$_closure4@54320707] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.2.0-beta.4@aar` to `com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:5.2.0-beta.3@aar` 
in your `build.gradle` file.

you can see the version 5.2.0-beta.3@aar [here](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/map-sdk/5.2.0-beta.3/). but there is nothing like 5.2.0-beta.4@aar. you can see not found [here](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/map-sdk/5.2.0-beta.4/). that is the issue.